# Extract urls from a string of html data

Tags: python, regex

I already tried to extract this html data with BeautifulSoup but it's only limited with tags. What I need to do is to get the trailing `something.html` or `some/something.html` after the prefix `www.example.com/products/` while eliminating the parameters like `?search=1`. I prefer to use regex with this but I don't know the exact pattern for this.

input:

```
System","urlKey":"ppath","value":[],"hidden":false,"locked":false}],"bizData":"Related+Categories=Mobiles","pos":0},"listItems":[{"name":"Sam-Sung B309i High Precision Smooth Keypad Mobile Phone ","nid":"250505808","icons":[],"productUrl":"//www.example.com/products/sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html?search=1", "image": ["//www.example.com/products/site/ammaxxllx.html], "https://www.example.com/site/kakzja.html
```

---

```
prefix = "www.example.com/products/"
# do something
# expected output: ['sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html', 'site/ammaxxllx.html']
```

Comment: It'd be super helpful to show a very clear `input` and then your desired `output` of the result.

Comment: Updated........

Comment: Is your input some JSON object?

Comment: Do you have known conditions for the "prefix" ? Can it be either `www.example.com/products/` or `www.example.com/`, for example ?

Comment: It would be like `"www.example.com/products/(\w+)[\]\?]"`, the part in the parentheses is the match.

Comment: @thelogicalkoan It's a combination of HTML and JSON, but for this case it doesn't matter.

Comment: @HolyDanna Yes the prefix is dynamic, like what you said it can be `www.example.com/products/` or `www.example2.co.uk/`.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you want to use `re` here - with a trick since I "?" will follow the "html" in a URI:

```
import re 

L = ["//www.example.com/products/ammaxxllx.html", "https://www.example.com/site/kakzja.html", "//www.example.com/products/sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html?search=1"]
prefix = "www.example.com/products/"

>>> [re.search(prefix+'(.*)html', el).group(1) + 'html' for el in L if prefix in el]
['ammaxxllx.html', 'sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html']
```

Comment: The input should be `System","urlKey":"ppath","value":[],"hidden":false,"locked":false}],"bizData":"Related+Categories=Mobiles","pos":0},"listItems":[{"name":"Sam-Sung B309i High Precision Smooth Keypad Mobile Phone ","nid":"250505808","icons":[],"productUrl":"//www.example.com/products/sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html?search=1", "image": ["//www.example.com/products/site/ammaxxllx.html], "https://www.example.com/site/kakzja.html` and not a list. While the output should be a list.

Comment: the input you give is not clean, do you have a dict, text as input?

Answer (score 0):

Though the above answer by using `re` module is just awesome. You could also work around without using the module. Like this:

```
prefix = 'www.example.com/products/'
L = ['//www.example.com/products/sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html?search=1', '//www.example.com/products/site/ammaxxllx.html', 'https://www.example.com/site/kakzja.html']
ans = []
for l in L:
    input_ = l.rsplit(prefix, 1)
    try:
        input_ = input_[1]
        ans.append(input_[:input_.index('.html')] + '.html')
    except Exception as e:
        pass
print ans
['sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html', 'site/ammaxxllx.html']
```

Comment: The input should be `System","urlKey":"ppath","value":[],"hidden":false,"locked":false}],"bizData":"Related+Categories=Mobiles","pos":0},"listItems":[{"name":"Sam-Sung B309i High Precision Smooth Keypad Mobile Phone ","nid":"250505808","icons":[],"productUrl":"//www.example.com/products/sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html?search=1", "image": ["//www.example.com/products/site/ammaxxllx.html], "https://www.example.com/site/kakzja.html` and not a list. While the output should be a list.

Comment: You asked how to parse the given URL with a specific pattern and not the input. If you also want answers for that then please update your question with proper input data.

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to use `urlparse` instead of/along with `re`

It will allow you to split a URL like this:

```
import urlparse

my_url = "http://www.example.com/products/ammaxxllx.html?spam=eggs#sometag"
url_obj = urlparse.urlsplit(my_url)

url_obj.scheme
>>> 'http'
url_obj.netloc
>>> 'www.example.com'
url_obj.path
>>> '/products/ammaxxllx.html'
url_obj.query
>>> 'spam=eggs'
url_obj.fragment
>>> 'sometag'

# Now you're able to work with every chunk as wanted! 
prefix = '/products'
if url_obj.path.startswith(prefix):
    # Do whatever you need, replacing the initial characters. You can use re here
    print url_obj.path[len(prefix) + 1:]
>>>> ammaxxllx.html
```

Comment: The input should be `System","urlKey":"ppath","value":[],"hidden":false,"locked":false}],"bizData":"Related+Categories=Mobiles","pos":0},"listItems":[{"name":"Sam-Sung B309i High Precision Smooth Keypad Mobile Phone ","nid":"250505808","icons":[],"productUrl":"//www.example.com/products/sam-sung-b309i-high-precision-smooth-keypad-mobile-phone-i250505808-s341878516.html?search=1", "image": ["//www.example.com/products/site/ammaxxllx.html], "https://www.example.com/site/kakzja.html` and not a list. While the output should be a list.